# Real time traffic data

Tags: java, web-services, api

I don't know if this is the place to ask the question but I 'll give it a go anyway. I'm looking for a web based service that can replace TMC over FM. I'm currently working on distance matrix between multiple points (>1000) and would like to take in account the real time traffic data. I know that google maps and [tom tom](http://developer.tomtom.com/) have the data but I'm looking for other serviceses as well (open source would be lovelly). I hope you guy's can help me out.